# How to use argument twice in printf in shell?

Tags: shell, zsh, printf

`printf %s%s one two` prints `onetwo` but I would like `oneonetwotwo`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In zsh:

```
printf '%1$s%1$s' one two
```

Where `%n$s` is like `%s` except that it uses the n<sup>th</sup> argument instead of the next one like the `printf()`¹ of the GNU libc (but not in the standalone GNU `printf` utility nor the `printf` builtin of the GNU shell (bash) yet).

That [was added to zsh in 2001](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2001/msg02715.html) and is also available in a few other `printf` implementations though with some variations and [will be specified in the next version of the POSIX standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=1592)

Note that while `printf '%s%1$s' one two` would also work in zsh, it does not in all `printf` implementations that support `%n$x` and POSIX will make the behaviour unspecified if directives with and without `n$` are mixed.

Another option is to use the array zipping operator, for instance in an anonymous function:

```
(){ printf %s%s ${argv:^argv}; } one two
```

Where with zip `$argv` with itself resulting in `one` `one` `two` `two` being passed to `printf`. As usual, change to `"${(@)argv:^argv}"` or `"${@:^argv}"` to preserve empty elements in any.

---

<sup>That `%$nX` syntax in `printf()` is POSIX, possibly originating in SVR4 (was in SVR4, not SVR3), probably coming from `nl_printf()` earlier used for localisation of messages where the order of elements in a message may change from one language to the next.</sup>

Comment: Probably it should be noted that the feature was intended to help localizations originally, so using it to duplicate an argument on output is just a special case.

Comment: `/usr/bin/printf` and the BSD libc function in MacOS support this. This is fun: `/usr/bin/printf '%1$s%0$s' one two` (zero is an undefined argument index). It outputs `one%1$s%0$stwoone` - don't use zero in both positions, it outputs the format string repeatedly forever (^C interrupts). Zero causes an error to be output in zsh.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, from `printf()`, it's standard (POSIX at least, not sure of C standard), I should probably make it clear.